# Specification of configuration file (log4j2.xml) for log4j as VM argument just working in eclipse

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

I'm using the new Log4j2 - Java Logging Framework. If I specify the path to the configuration file in eclipse as VM argument `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/../config.xml` everything works fine. The configure file is loaded and the logging works as expected, i.e. all logs are written to files. If I additionally use the `-Dlog4j.debug`, I get the corresponding debug messages from the framework which confirms the correct loading of my configuration file.

However, when I use ANT with a build.xml file the logging framework seems to be initialized with the default configuration - the logs no longer written to the files but to the console. I start the created prog.jar file with the following statement from the console:

`java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/../config.xml -Dlog4j.debug -jar prog.jar`

The only debug message I get from to Log4j2 framework is the following:

> DEBUG StatusLogger org.slf4j.helpers.Log4jLoggerFactory is not on classpath. Good!

In the following, parts of the build.xml file which I use to create prog.jar:

```
  <target name="init">
    <tstamp/>
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

 <path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib}/apache-log4j-2.11.1-bin/">
        <include name="log4j-api-2.11.1.jar"/>
        <include name="log4j-core-2.11.1.jar"/>
    </fileset>
 </path>

  <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source">
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="true">
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
  </target>

  <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution">
    <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/prog.jar" basedir="${build}" compress="true">
      <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java"/>
      <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib}/apache-log4j-2.11.1-bin/" includes="*.jar" />
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="ch.zwas.aks.Runner"/>
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
```

I'm confused why it works using Eclipse but does apparently not work when I create the project with ANT and specify the configuration file in the console. Furthermore, I have no idea why there are no more debug messages when I run the jar from the console.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: I know I am off topic, but have you considered converting your project to maven? You basically put your dependencies under the `<dependencies>` section, and you xml config file under `resources`

Comment: @Daniele The problem is that im restricted to use ANT in the end..

Comment: The error message that you got in console seems related to missing `log4j-slf4j-impl.jar` I think your code is using slf4j library and while running program from eclipse somehow, this jar is available but not in case of console and ant project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint of Vikas Sachdeva I was able to solve the problem. The problem was that I apparently packed too many jar files from the log4j library into `prog.jar`. When I include just the following jar files it works as expected with ANT / console as well.

```
junit-X.jar
log4j-api-X.ja
log4j-core-X.jar
slf4j-api-X.jar
slf4j-simple-X.jar
```

The other jars which came with the log4j library I left out. It seems that Eclipse ignores these, but when included with the build.xml into to finally jar then they cause trouble.